# only last scraped items adding to DF while scraping with selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, data-mining

im crawling a website, everything works pretty well except appending data into DataFrame ;

```
def function(selector,name ,driver) :
df = pd.DataFrame()
try:
    data = {}

    result = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))).text
    print(name , result)
    data.update( {name : result} )


except Exception as e:
    data.update( {name : " "} )
finally :
    df = df.append(data,ignore_index= True)
return df

df=function(".home span" , "team1_name",driver )
df=function(".away span" , "team2_name",driver )
df=function(".home strong+ strong" , "team1_position",driver )
df=function(".away strong+ strong" , "team2_position",driver )
```

the result always is the last scraped item which is team2_position.
what is the best way to append my data into dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you are overwriting your df while holing the returns from your function. can use like below:

```
df.append(function(".home span" , "team1_name",driver ))
```

Instead of:

```
df =  function(".home span" , "team1_name",driver )
```

Comment: following ur guide i get the error :  name 'df' is not defined

Comment: Define a data frame as df before using it .

Answer (score 0):

******* hey  a small change here and rest everything is fine

As you are appending inside the function ,note the action is append is successfull ,but it is temporary as u return that outside u need to append it after function call ,as always you are returning to the same variable again and again ,it is getting overwritten in the variable "df" , so whatever assigned at the last is stored in that variable ,

so you can do this in many ways

1. Just replace those last four lines with the below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(function(".home span" , "team1_name",driver ))
df.append(function(".away span" , "team2_name",driver ))
df.append(function(".home strong+ strong" , "team1_position",driver ))
df.append(function(".away strong+ strong" , "team2_position",driver ))
```

2. 

change the code as follows ,just copy past this

```
def function(selector,name ,driver,df) :

try:
    data = {}

    result = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))).text
    print(name , result)
    data.update( {name : result} )


except Exception as e:
    data.update( {name : " "} )
finally :
    df = df.append(data,ignore_index= True)
return df

df = pd.DataFrame()
df=function(".home span" , "team1_name",driver,df)
df=function(".away span" , "team2_name",driver ,df)
df=function(".home strong+ strong" , "team1_position",driver ,df)
df=function(".away strong+ strong" , "team2_position",driver ,df)
```

3. 

as we did in type1 )---->
you can define a function to append the returned temporary dataFrames to the Final DataFrame
and can invoke the function within the function name "function" so when we call this function "function" it automatically calls another function written to append and job is done.